# Is it possible to solve $AB^{-1}C = x$ without doing any inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

**Problem**: I would like to solve the respective equation:  $$A * B^{-1} *  C =
x$$ without inverting $B$, because of their giant dimensions $(6\cdot
 10^5\times 6\cdot 10^5)$.

$x$ is a scalar, $A$ and $C$ are vectors with $(1\times6\cdot 10 ^5)$ and  $(6\cdot 10 ^5\times 1)$ respectively.

**Question**: Is it possible to manipulate this expression so that the final expression does not contain any inverse matrix?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Are you trying to solve for something or just to calculate $X$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: What are you given and what are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Something like the LR decomposition or else could be for you.

Comment: I assume you are given $A,B,C$ but are not a priori given $B^{-1}$, and you want to obtain $x$. In this case you need to solve either the system $By=C$ or the system $yB=A$, and then compute either $Ay$ or $yC$ depending on which system you solved. That can be done without an inverse using any method for linear systems (so presumably either Gaussian elimination or some iterative method). Sadly I don't think there is any shortcut way to solve one system or the other, without special assumptions about a relationship between $B$ and one of $A$ or $C$.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, we are given $A$, $B$ and $C$ and we want to solve for for $x$. The catch is that we do want to spend time inverting $B$. Is this correct?

Comment: Factorization Theorems:
This chapter highlights a few of the many factorization theorems for matrices. While some factorization results are relatively direct, others are iterative. While some factorization results serve to simplify the solution to
linear systems, others are concerned with revealing the matrix eigenvalues.
We consider both types of results here 

https://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/m640_03c/lectures/chapter7.pdf

Comment: I admit that I put the question badly, I am new at this. This expression is one of the constraints of an otimization problem, when $A B^{-1} C > x$, and C and x are unknown. 
However, my question is: Did I have to compute the inverse of $B$ to solve this constraint? Or can I obtain an equivalent expression with no inverse matrix?